# Openlayes - Loading 3 different KMLs via proxy; one appears and the others don't

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I'm loading 3 KMLs using an ashx handler taken from http://code.google.com/p/iisproxy. The 3 KMLs I'm trying to load are Openlayers sundials ( http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml/sundials.kml ), Marine Traffic KML ( http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/ge_marinetraffic.kml ), and flightwise ( http://mw1.google.com/mw-earth-vectordb/flightwise/flightwise_root.kml ).

The Sundial is working for me, but the other 2 don't.
I'm afraid the problem is because the other 2 KMLs have file links inside while sundials KML has data only.

Is there a way I can make the other two work on my IIS?

This is the code I used:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

function init() {

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/proxy.ashx?url=";

    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

    var flight = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Flightwise", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://mw1.google.com/mw-earth-vectordb/flightwise/flightwise_root.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        })
    })

    var marine = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Marine", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/ge_marinetraffic.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        })
    })

    var sundials = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Sundials", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml/sundials.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        })
    })

    map.addLayers([osm, flight, marine, sundials]);

    var controls = [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),                        
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),                        
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),                        
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                    /*new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),*/
                    new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                ];

    map.addControls(controls);


    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For fetching remoteData, the maxDepth option must be greater than 0.
>   This option tells the KML parser how far the traverse before giving
>   up. 
>   [Source](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/formats.html)

Try adding `maxDepth: 20` or something. Play around with the number. I imagine you might have to go deep for the AIS data. Not sure.

```js
...
format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
    extractStyles: true,
    extractAttributes: true,
    maxDepth: 20
})
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , sadly this didn't work for me.
Maybe I did something wrong... if you were able to do it , Ill be happy to see how.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't overlayed KMLs with network links. I just figured it was worth a try.

Comment: Hope anyone can help here.

Comment: pretty old question, but if you try the network link directly it will work.  Your flightwise kml doesn't have 'Document' tag, which is needed for it to work on openlayers.  Try the link inside [flightwise](http://mw1.google.com/mw-weather/flightwise/pointer.kml) instead. (but that one doesn't seem to work anymore now)